# Issue normalising json and using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, database-normalization

I have an issue where I am trying to normalise my json response

Json example:

```
{
   "data":{
      "flavors":[
                 {
                  "name":"Basic_A4",
                  "cpu_number":8,
                  "ram":14336,
                  "last_price":"0.200",
                  "currency":"USD"
                  },
                  {...}
            ],
      "aws":[
                  {
                  "name":"md5.xlarge",
                  "cpu_number":2,
                  "ram":14336,
                  "last_price":"0.100",
                  "currency":"USD"
                  },
                  {...}
            ]
   }
}
```

My Code:

```
df_values = pd.json_normalize(content['data']['flavors']['aws'],meta=['name', 'cpu_number', 'ram', 'last_price', 'currency'])
        for index, row in df_values.iterrows():
                df1 = df1.append(row)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

When using the following code it works but i don't get the data from the AWS array

```
    df_values = pd.json_normalize(content['data']['flavors'],meta=['name', 'cpu_number', 'ram', 'last_price', 'currency'])
            for index, row in df_values.iterrows():
                    df1 = df1.append(row)
```

Output I want:

| name | cpu_number | ram | last_price | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Basic_A4 | 8 | 14336 | 0.200 | USD |
| example2 | 4 | 14336 | 0.100 | USD |
| md5.xlarge | 2 | 14336 | 0.100 | USD |
| example4 | 2 | 7324 | 0.055 | USD |

update: I have now used the suggested method however i'm having issues with my new json

```
{
   "data":{
      "flavors":[
                 {
                  "name":"Basic_A4",
                  "cpu_number":8,
                  "ram":14336,
                  "last_price":"0.200",
                  "currency":"USD"
                  "provider": {
                    "name": "Azure"
                  }
                 }
            ],
      "aws":[
                  {
                  "name":"md5.xlarge",
                  "cpu_number":2,
                  "ram":14336,
                  "last_price":"0.100",
                  "currency":"USD"
                  "provider": {
                    "name": "AWS"
                  }
                 }
            ]
   }
}
```

The table now looks like this:

```
| name| cpu_number| ram| last_price| currency| provider|
|---- |------| -----|-----|-----|-----|
| Basic_A4| 8| 14336|0.200|USD| {'name': 'Azure'}|
| example2| 4| 14336|0.100|USD| {'name': 'Azure'}|
| md5.xlarge| 2| 14336|0.100|USD| {'name': 'AWS'}|
| example4| 2| 7324|0.055|USD| {'name': 'AWS'}|
```

I want it to look like this:

| name | cpu_number | ram | last_price | currency | provider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Basic_A4 | 8 | 14336 | 0.200 | USD | Azure |

thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file, called `data.json` (In my example):

```
{
    "data":{
       "flavors":[
                  {
                   "name":"Basic_A4",
                   "cpu_number":8,
                   "ram":14336,
                   "last_price":"0.200",
                   "currency":"USD"
                   }
             ],
       "aws":[
                   {
                   "name":"md5.xlarge",
                   "cpu_number":2,
                   "ram":14336,
                   "last_price":"0.100",
                   "currency":"USD"
                   }
             ]
    }
 }
```

Read `.json` file and parse it to a dataframe with `chain` and `itertools`.

```
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from itertools import chain

# read your json file
file = 'data.json'
with open(file) as train_file:
    dict_train = json.load(train_file)

# parse it into a dataframe
dftemp = list(chain.from_iterable(dict_train["data"].values()))

tempArr = []
for i in dftemp:
    tempArr.append(i["provider"]["name"])

dftemp = pd.DataFrame(dftemp)
dftemp["provider"] = tempArr

dftemp

         name  cpu_number    ram last_price currency provider
0    Basic_A4           8  14336      0.200      USD    Azure
1  md5.xlarge           2  14336      0.100      USD      AWS
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, one slight change, i have edited the original question

Comment: I have edited my code, so it should fit to your example now.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to above answer, you can do it like this:

```
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = {
   "data":{
      "flavors":[
                 {
                  "name":"Basic_A4",
                  "cpu_number":8,
                  "ram":14336,
                  "last_price":"0.200",
                  "currency":"USD"
                  },
                  {...}
            ],
      "aws":[
                  {
                  "name":"md5.xlarge",
                  "cpu_number":2,
                  "ram":14336,
                  "last_price":"0.100",
                  "currency":"USD"
                  },
                  {...}
            ]
   }
}
result = json_normalize(data['data']["flavors"])
result2 = json_normalize(data['data']["aws"])
df_new = pd.concat([result,result2], axis=0)
df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df_new)
```

Comment: this is exactly what i currently have, it will only show the flavors data and not the aws data.

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope it solves the problem